# How to show that continuous functions in $L^1$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How to show that for continuous functions in $L^1$ is Riemann integrable in other words.
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \, d \lambda=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f \, dx
\end{align*}

I already showed that the other direction is true. But I could use results such as if function is Riemann integrable then it is bounded. Not really sure how to show this direction.

Also, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f \, dx=\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{-N}^N f \, dx$

Comment: It is not true. Take $f=1_\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say continuos as well. I will add it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you mean integrable as an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by improper?

Comment: Riemann integration is defined for functions on intervals of the form $[a,b]$.

Comment: I see. I will add this part too.

Comment: If it is continuous, then it has a Riemann integral on $[-N,N]$ and this will equal the corresponding Lebesgue integral. Then use the fact that it is $L^1$ to show that the improper Riemann integral on the real line exists.

Comment: This second step. How does one show that. $L^1$ is a statement about Lebesgue integral. How do I connect it Riemann integral

Comment: If you establish that the integrals are equal on $[-N,N]$ then the $\lim_{N \to \infty}$ exists for the Lebesgue integral, hence for the improper Riemann integral.

Comment: So, suppose we have that $\int_{[-N,N]} f d \lambda=\int_{-N}^N f dx$. My question is. Can I now simply take the limit?

Comment: Yes, you know the limit on the left hand side exists by assumption, hence the right hand side has the same limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I already showed that the other direction is true. "

There is only one direction to this problem.

Given $f$ is improper Riemann integrable and continuous, $f$ might not be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, take $f(x) = x$.

Given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is continuous, then the improper Riemann integral exists and it is equal to the Lebesgue integral. Let $f_n = f\chi_{[-n,n]}$, we see that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. and $|f_n|\leq |f|$, by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f\;d\lambda = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f_n \;d\lambda= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n f \;d\lambda= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n f\;dx. $$
And as you asked, can we simply take this limit? 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n f\;dx $$
Yes, we can. So how do we know the limit exists? If you look at the first term in the equation, the limit exists because it equals to $\int_\mathbb{R} f\;d\lambda$.